# Datepicker Bootstrap: detecting only when it clicked on the date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using datepicker for bootstrap from this site http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker

I want to alert the date value when it clicked on date. I have these codes:

HTML:

```
<div id="datepicker" class="input-append date pull-right" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date="12-02-2012">
    <input class="span2" type="text" value="12-02-2012" size="16" style=" width:95px;"></input>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
    alert($(this).data('date'));
});
```

It's works, but when i click month or year, it's also alerting. How do i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Try `alert($(this).text());`

Answer (score 0):

Try`onselect` event of daatepicker

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({

onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
     alert(dateText)
      }
})
```

> Called when the datepicker is selected. The function receives the
>   selected date as text and the datepicker instance as parameters. this
>   refers to the associated input field.

OR

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
     alert(ev.date);
     console.log(ev);
});
```

**EDIT:** *parse date from Wed Sep 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time) to 11-9-2013*

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){

console.log(ev);
var d =new Date(Date.parse(ev.date));
dateString =(d.getDate()+1)+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ d.getFullYear();
alert(dateString)
console.log(dateString)
});
```

[**bootstrap-datepicker**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

[**option-onSelect**](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

Comment: dianuj thanks for answering.
your second codes return this:
 "Wed Sep 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)"
could you tell me how to get only the date with dd-mm-yyyy format? thanks

Comment: @MuhammadRizkiRijal Try this one `var d =new Date(Date.parse('Wed Sep 11 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)'));
dateString =(d.getDate()+1)+"-"+(d.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ d.getFullYear();
alert(dateString)
console.log(dateString)`